# Why React SetState is not working as expected?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, promise

I have this code, in my React component:
(__loadItems() returns a Promise.)

```
componentDidMount(){
    const self=this;
    this.__loadItems().then((itemsCollection) => {
        // below will log what I expect:
        console.log('itemsCollection', itemsCollection);

        self.setState( (state, props) => {


             return {
                 itemTypes: itemsCollection,
             };
        }, () => {
        //below will contain what expected
        console.log(self.state.itemTypes);
        //ISSUE: state.itemTypes will be Array(0)
        console.log(self.state);

        // });
    });
}
```

Why my state itemTypes won't be set as expected?

```
 console.log(self.state)
```

will output:

```
 { itemTypes: Array(0)}
```

Comment: `setState` does not work that way. Try with `self.setState({ itemTypes: itemsCollection}, () => { //... })`

Comment: `setState` does work that way - however if you don't merge with your existing state other fields will be deleted. Are you sure that `itemsCollections` contains data?

Comment: Yes first log does print expected data. What do you mean by merge? Shouldnt it merge itself whats returned by setState?

Comment: setState is async, if you want to console log your new state after it has been changed you have to do something like this 
``self.setState({itemTypes:itemsCollection},()=>{console.log(self.state)})``

Comment: Infact I’m checking state in the callback section. But still state is not what I would expect

Comment: Sorry I've realised that the code is working. Issue is with Google chrome console logging. It is logging  { itemTypes: Array(0)} . But if I expand the object the Array does contain the expected payload... It's not Array(0) but Array(n)

Answer (score 0):

It is just simple works for me, I do not see the problem. Also the callback logs the items.

```js
const loadItems = () => (
  new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(['item1', 'item2']), 1500);
  })
)

class App extends React.Component { 
  state = { items: [] };
  
  componentDidMount(){
    loadItems().then(items => this.addItemsToState(items))
  }
  
  addItemsToState = items => {
    this.setState({ items }, console.log(items))
  }
  
  render() {
    const { items } = this.state;
    return <ul>{items.map(item => <li>{item}</li>)}</ul>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to the Console log itself.
I was using Google chrome and seems that the printed console.log json object's preview was
referring to the initial state before loading. With an empty array:

```
  { itemTypes: Array(0)}
```

I haven't tried to expand this preview because Array(0) I'd expect to see nothing inside.

Instead by expanding the wanted payload response is there even though Array(0) was declared.

Tricky and confusing.